# How Many Ways 5 Objects Can Be Selected With Replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, sampling

Suppose I have the following set up:

- There are 5 objects : A, B, C, D, E
- The probability for each of these objects to be chosen is : 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1
- You want to pick 5 of these objects with replacement (e.g. ABACD, DDBCA, etc.)

I want to find out (exact solution):

- **All combinations that can be made from these 5 objects**

In a previous question on a different Stackoverflow Community (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375997/creating-probability-trees-in-r), I learned how to enumerate all these combinations for this problem using the R programming language:

```
library(RcppAlgos)

# Probabilities
probs <- setNames(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1), LETTERS[1:5])

# Generate permutations
perms <- permuteGeneral(names(probs), repetition = TRUE)

# Collapse permutations
perm_res <- do.call(paste, c(asplit(perms, 2), sep = ""))

# Replace with probability values and coerce to numeric
perms[] <- probs[perms]
class(perms) <- "numeric"

# Calculate products
res <- data.frame(perm_res, prob = exp(rowSums(log(perms))))
```

Based on this, it appears that there 3125 different combinations that can be made:

```
dim(res)
[1] 3125    2
```

**My Question:** What mathematical formula can be used to calculate this number 3125? And is there a general mathematical formula that can be used for "n" objects with with "m" choices with replacement? E.g. Picking 11 objects with replacement?

- I know that this is not a "factorial" question, i.e. there are not 5! ways to choose these objects
- I know that this question does not correspond to the power set, i.e. there are not 2^5 ways to choose these objects
- I know that is not a typical combinatorics problem, i.e. I don't think this can be solved directly using "nCr"

Can someone please show me what mathematical formula can be used to determine this number 3125?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason that neither combinations nor permutations are pertinent is that you are sampling with replacement.  If you were sampling without replacement, then either combinations or permutations would be pertinent, depending on whether the order of the selection of the items was deemed relevant.

Comment: The answer of lafinur, which I agree with, presumes that the order of selection of the $5$ items is relevant.  Thus, the selection of $A,A,A,B,B$ is deemed distinct from the selection of $B,B,A,A,A$.  A much tougher question is: What is the enumeration when you are sampling with replacement, but the order of selection is deemed not relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are choosing $5$ elements of a set of $5$. For the first element, there are $5$ possible outcomes. Because there is replacement, for the second element there are also $5$ possible outcomes, for the third the same, etc...

This results in $5\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5 = 5^5=3125$ possible selections with replacement.

In general, if you are selecting with replacement $n$ elements of a set of $m$ elements, there are $m^n$ selections.